# Changing the name of a Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I created a Facebook Page for a web site and had the page match the name of the site.

Since then, the website has since changed its name and I need to update the Facebook Page to reflect this.

Is it possible to change the Facebook Page name?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Facebook Help Center says:

> If an error was made in your Page name
>   when it was created, you have the
>   option to edit the Page name to
>   correct this issue. This option is
>   only limited to Pages with **less than 100 connections**. After selecting to
>   edit your Page, you can adjust this
>   information from the "Basic
>   Information" section.

Comment: Alas, we are somewhat more popular than that. :-(

Answer (score 1):

You can change name of the page with few easy steps until you reach 200 likes

go to edit page --->update page info-->click on page name--->edit name-->save changes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can request a change to your facebook page. Go to `About`, then `Page Info` and select the edit pencil on the right of your page's name. This takes you to a form to request the name change. I get the impression it is a manual process since they ask you to upload something that proves the address of your company. That's the bit I'm struggling with.